# Meaning of *trope*

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trope)

(noun)1 ***Trope***: a figurative or metaphorical use of a word or expression.

ex.

"...both clothes and illness became tropes for new attitudes toward the self."

Could someone explain the meaning of "trope" per Definition 1 and the usage in this example  in layman terms?

Comment: The meaning of which? Trope, or the expression?

Comment: To explain the expression, it will definitely help to know where it came from. Please note that **all** references and quotes (including from dictionaries) [**must** have citations.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: As the dictionary says: *"a significant or recurrent theme; a motif."*

Comment: The quote is from Lexico. It sounds like a bad example to me.

Comment: Apologies, @user349217: You didn't mix them up: Lexico did. You never stood a chance!

Answer (score 2):

The word "trope" has two meanings.

I think [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trope)'s examples are attached to the wrong definitions!

The second definition is:

> A significant or recurrent theme; a motif.

So your quote says, "Both clothes and illness became significant or recurrent themes for new attitudes toward the self."

Without the context it's hard to explain any further. Perhaps people's attitudes to clothes and to illness began to reveal how they thought about themselves.

Comment: The example is given  at the first definition  **by** Lexico, not the OP. Hence the confusion. That said...perhaps Lexico screwed up the citation?

Comment: @Cascabel Yes! Well well. Lexico screwed up.